# Help for wall pattern

Tags: modeling, texturing

Anyone knows how to do that type of wall pattern please ?
[image]

Best regards

Comment: Hello :). Do you need actual geometry or a texture?

Comment: A geometry would be better but someone just told me how to do that below ! Thanks anyway :p

Comment: Yeah, moonboots is the best :)

Answer (score 5):

You could:

- Create a plane, subdivide:

[image]

- Give it a *Decimate* modifier / *Collapse* mode, with a ratio of 0.5, apply:

[image]

- Select all in *Edit* mode and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to triangulate:

[image]

- Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Poke Faces*:

[image]

- Bring a bit more chaos with some vertices move if you want, then select one triangle center and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > *Amount of connecting edges* to select all the triangle centers:

[image]

- Move them up:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use these Modifiers to make what you want

and this is my plane :

[image]